# Change weekdays's header in datepicker

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui-datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I want to change the weekdays's name to a string array like
From

```
$scope.dateOptions = {formatDayHeader: 'QTX'}
```

[image]

something like

```
`$scope.dateOptions = {formatDayHeader: ["b","c","c","c","c","c","c"]}`
```

(this isn't worked because formatDayHeader only accepts string)

I know that i can replace day's name in angular.js. Is there any way to change directly in dateOptions?

Comment: You could override the default template used by the date picker with the `template-url` option. You can refer to the templates used by default to help you customise the day headers. https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/template/datepicker

Comment: template only change day/month/year. can it be used to change weekdays's name?

Comment: I think you missed my point. If you specify a custom template, you're in control of the entire look of the date picker. Did you actually look inside `day.html`? This is the default template used when the date picker is at the day-level granularity. Around line 10, you'll see that the default currently binds the shortened weekday name.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but i don't understand how that line work...